# How can I merge thousands of polygons in Oracle Spatial in faster way?

Tags: performance, oracle-spatial

Previously I was using  sdo_aggr_union(sdoaggrtype(geom, 0.005)) to get boundary polygon by merging geometries, which was taking at least 3 minutes in case of 4000 polygons.

Even if I use merging of polygons by choosing block by block of polygons set, its still taking 30 seconds. (Refer Oracle Complex spatial queries: Examples C-4).

Is there any other approach to achieve such result in minimum time?

Comment: From my experience Oracle is just sluggish. I have heard that Oracle 12 is faster but I have not tried it.

Comment: Could you try simplifying the geometries beforehand with `SDO_UTIL.SIMPLIFY`?

I'm guessing not as you've specified a small tolerance, but this may help with performance if you've overly detailed input geometries.

Comment: Upgrade to Oracle 12c (12.1.0.2) and make sure to enable the Spatial Vector Accelerator (only if you have the proper Oracle Spatial and Graph license - this is not available with Oracle Locator). Depending on your hardware (cpu capacity), merging your 4000 polygons will complete in a second or less.